# Keep specific tag

Tags: r

According to this code someone can remove html tags

```
#remove html tags
cleanFun <- function(htmlString) {
  return(gsub("<.*?>", "", htmlString))
}
```

How can someone modify it to keep the start and end of

tag only and remove anything else?

Example input:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("<h1>keep </h1> also here <li> remove this tag </li> and <h1> this </h1>", "one more example <h2> false alarm </h2>"))
```

Expected output:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("<h1>keep </h1> also here remove this tagand <h1> this </h1>", "one more example false alarm"))
```

Comment: Can you show an example

Comment: @akrun yes I added

Comment: Could you provide another example or detail your example? I am not sure I get it

Comment: Based on your example, not clear what the start and end tag